# Time Series Forecasting in SageMaker - which instance should I choose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-sagemaker, arima

I am currently trying to forecasting hourly values with a weekly seasonality. In the `SARIMAX` model that means that I have to set m = 168 (24 hours a day and 7 days a week -> 24*7).

My model looks like this:

```
model = SARIMAX(df['IdCount'],order=(4,1,3),seasonal_order=(2,2,1,168))
results = model.fit()
```

And I think because of the relatively big `m=168` it takes a very long time to fit the model. When doing this locally, the kernel died.

Therefore, I chose to try it in SageMaker and I am currently using ml.t2.medium instance. In order to perform this task fast and without any issues which instance would you recommend and why? Which is the best one only in regards to performance and which is the best one regarding cost benefit ratio?

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about `SARIMAX`, but what I do with sagemaker is this.. I choose for the notebook the cheapest instance which is `ml.t2.medium` and then I use the notebook to launch the training job. For that training job I usually choose an instance with GPU. Anyway `ml.t2.medium` is very basic and I would not recommend it for anything else of what I do (launch other instances). You can take a look at [this](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/pricing/?nc1=h_ls) page for the available instance types, their features  and also their price.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sounds like a suitable approach!